# Observable Collection do not update the UI

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I am working on the ability to add and delete rows in an observable collection.
I have UserControl view with the ListView bound to the ObservableCollection.
I have also delete command with is working in the ViewModel but don't update the UI.

This is my code on the ViewModel with is inherit from MvvmLight ViewModelBase class.

```
 public class ProductInfoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _productList;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
    {
        get { return _productList; }
        set
        {
            _productList =  value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductList");
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Constructor
    public ProductInfoViewModel()
    {
        ConnectWebService connect = new ConnectWebService();
        string json = connect.getResponse(@"http://localhost:8082/products");
        ProductList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Product>>(json);
        DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<long>((id) => DeleteCommandHandler(id, ProductList));
    }
    #endregion
    #region Commands
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }
    #endregion
    #region CommandsHandlers
    private void DeleteCommandHandler(long id, ObservableCollection<Product> productList)
    {
        try
        {
            productList.Remove(productList.Where(i => i.ProductId == id).First());

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is my code in XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ProductInfoViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="0,50,0,100">
        <ListView  Margin="5" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                   x:Name="ProductList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Kod" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductCode}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Nazwa" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Typ" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductType}" />
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Opis" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductDescription}" />
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Dostępność" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductAvability}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Edytuj" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Blue" Width="50" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        Click="Button_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Usuń" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Blue" Width="50" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Click="Delete_Click" Command="{Binding ProductInfoView.DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}"
                                         />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

My product class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but I also use Fody.

Right now the view is updating only when I changing a view to another and then go back.
I can't figure out what is wrong. 
I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: A side note: you don't need `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for the `ItemsSource` binding. It's useless, because an `ItemsControl` will never change the items source object reference.

Comment: It seems odd that the DeleteCommandHandler has the productList parameter. It could as well operate directly on the ProductList property. That said, did you make sure that it is actually called, and that the passed ProductId is valid, i.e. no exception is thrown (which you then ignore by means of an empty catch block)?

Comment: I deleted try, catch block (i use that becouse when i deleted item from list it still occurs in UI, and i get exception when i hit delete trigger again) I change also productList parameter for ProductList property directly, but problem still exist like it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the `Command` property of the `Button` to the view model returned by your `Locator` resource. You should bind it to the same instance that the `ListView` is bound to:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="Usuń" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Blue" Width="50" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Click="Delete_Click"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you delete items from the list you do not use your product list setter so `RaisePropertyChanged` does not get called. a quick fix would be to add a call to `RaisePropertyChanged` after you remove an item:

```
productList.Remove(productList.Where(i => i.ProductId == id).First());
RaisePropertyChanged("ProductList");
```

Comment: That's not necessary, because productList is an ObservableCollection.